# Deploying both Rails and Node.js in a single Heroku Cedar App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, heroku

Is this possible using the proc file?  I have an idea for an application that would use both Rails and Node+Socket.io and the ability to deploy both systems in one place would be amazing.

Comment: Nope. It would seem like you could, but I'm still unsure.

Comment: I am also looking for an example of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep them separate myself, mainly down to the fact that it's two very different stacks that could easily diverge in the future.

Bear in mind that you're not charged per app on Heroku, and you can also share databases / other resources with no bother at all.

Comment: How do you set up two apps to share a common DB on Heroku?  Sounds like an awesome feature that I've seen no documentation on.

Comment: There's a couple of ways.  Either you update the ENV var DATABASE_URL to point at the other apps DB (heroku config:add..) or you can use heroku pg:promote (which is the supported method).

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql